# Is the function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the function $f(z) = z^m(\overline z)^n$
for non-negative integers $m$ and $n$. Is $f$
holomorphic in any open subset of $ \Bbb C$?

I know that for a function to be holomorphic I need to show $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists. So should I consider cases where $m=0, n=0$ and $m=1,n=1$ separately or should I try to work with $f(z)$ using $z=x+iy$ directly?

Comment: Do you know any tests for holomophicity (or a related property) other than that limit definition of the derivative?

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic iff $\frac{{\partial f(z)}}{{\partial \bar z}}  \equiv  0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $n=0$, we have $f(z)=z^m$ which is trivially holomorphic in $\mathbb C$. So let suppose $n \gt 0$ in what follows.

You know that $g_m(z)=z^m$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C$. As the ratio of two holomorphic maps is holomorphic if the denominator doesn't vanish, if $f$ was holomorphic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0 \}$, $z \mapsto \overline{z}^n$ would also be. As it isn't the case for $n \gt 0$, $f$ is not holomorphic in any open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.

Now at $z_0=0$, you have $\vert f(z)/z \vert \le \vert z \vert$ for $\vert z \vert \le 1$ and $m \ge 2$. Hence $f$ is complex differentiable in that case at $0$. And you'll see that for $m \in \{0,1\}$ $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $n=0$.

**Conclusion**

$f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C$ for $n=0$. Otherwise, for any open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb C$, $f$ is not holomorphic in $U$.

Comment: @RudytheReindeer A constant map $h$ is holomorphic as $h(z) - h(z_0)=0$ for any $z,z_0 \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: It is! 0_o : ) (comment must be at least 15 characters long)

Comment: Good answer, but at the end you claim that $f$ may be holomorphic at $0$ in some special cases. But it's just complex differentiable, not holomorphic (which means complex differentiable in an open set, not just a point).

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks for the comment. I updated the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "isomorphic" in the second paragraph?

Comment: @Gary Typo. I meant holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the claim you are trying to show is: "$f$ is holomorphic for all $n$ and all $m$ in $\mathbb Z$".

If a function is holomorphic it will satisfy the [Cauchy Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).

Does your $f$ satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations for all $n$ and all $m$?

Take for example $n=m=1$. If in this case your $f$ does not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations then you have shown that the claim is false because if $f$ does not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations then $f$ is not holomorphic.

To show $A$ implies $B$ you can show that not $B$ implies not $A$ (logical contraposition).